# I tried to implement in my site animate.css, it is only working for ready(load) Event of jQuery, it is not working for other mouse events?

Tags: jquery, css

```
$('#div').ready(function () {
    $('#div').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
});
```

It is working fine for the above code.

But it is not working for the below code.

```
 $('#TextBox1').on('click', function () {  
     $('#TextBox1').addClass('animated shake');
 });
```

How to resolve this??

This is my complete code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"     Inherits="_Default" %>

<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head2" runat="server">
<title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/motion-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link href="script/motion-ui-starter/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<link href="script/motion-ui-starter/css/motion-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="script/motion-ui-starter/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="script/motion-ui-starter/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="script/motion-ui-starter/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>

<style>
    .animated {
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-delay: 0s;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
    }

    .flash {
        animation-delay: 3s;
    }

    .auto-style1 {
        width: 100%;
        border: 2px solid #000066;
        background-color: #cccccc;
    }

    .auto-style4 {
        width: 513px;
        height: 44px;
    }

    .auto-style7 {
        height: 52px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .auto-style9 {
        height: 44px;
        width: 1403px;
    }

    .auto-style10 {
        height: 53px;
    }
</style>
<script src="script/motion-ui-starter/js/script.js"></script>
<script src="script/motion-ui-starter/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/motion-ui-starter/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script/motion-ui-starter/js/vendor/motion-ui.js"></script>

<script src="script/motion-ui-starter/css/Java.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#div').ready(function () {
        $('#div').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');

    });

    $('#TextBox1').on('click', function () {
        $('#TextBox1').addClass('animated shake');

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 63px; left: 2px; width: 280px; height: 203px; bottom: 513px;" id="div">
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7" colspan="2"><strong>Login Here</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4">User ID</td>
                <td class="auto-style9">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="43px" Style="margin-left: 15px" Width="194px" CssClass="animated flash"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4">Password</td>
                <td class="auto-style9">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="44px" Style="margin-left: 14px" Width="196px" CssClass="animated flash"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style10" colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Height="36px" Text="LOGIN" Width="94px" />
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Webpage gets animated when I click any button on webpage, how to stop this animation? How to make the transition should animate only once?

Comment: Is the click handler being called ? Can you put a console/alert and check ? Can you please share the jsfiddle also. Seems to be a small mistake which can be resolved easily.

Comment: Can you show your html ?

Comment: Put your `click` handler inside your `ready` handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
        $('#TextBox1').on('click', function () {
            $('#TextBox1').addClass('animated shake');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The event binding should work correctly (with a guarantee) once the DOM is ready.

Comment: now it is working. if i click any button inside the page again it starts to  animate.. how to stop it?

Comment: if i use only click it is not working.                                             $('#TextBox1').on('click', function () {
            $(this).addClass('animated shake');
        });

Comment: That's probably some different issue. Do you see any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the id will be set as "ct100_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1" in place where you have `TextBox1`. This is because you have the `runat="server"` specified.

**Note:** Always make sure you write the scripts which bind events to the elements inside the `$(document).ready(function(){ ....});` event. This will make sure the event is bound when all the elements have completed loading.

`Solution 1:` **Make the TextBox to have Static Id.**

Set the TextBox to have static Id. Add `ClientIDMode="Static"` into your textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Height="43px" Style="margin-left: 15px" Width="194px" CssClass="animated flash"></asp:TextBox>
```

This will make sure your id is not changed and the Script in Jquery can access id correctly.

---

`Solution 2` : **Change your script to use the clientId.**

`$("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>")` in place of `$("#TextBox1")`

So your script will be like below

```
 $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').on('click', function () {  
   $(this).addClass('animated shake');  // use $(this) as it will pint to the clicked textbox itself
 });
```

---

Answered similar stuff here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36695435/2592042